# Вывод из базы

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Здравствуйте. Я сделал вывод себе вывод всех столбцов в базе данных, но у меня выдает ошибку **Ошибочный запрос к БДYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group ORDER BY id DESC' at line 1** ошибки я вообще ни где здесь не вижу.

Вот такой скрипт:

```
<?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM group ORDER BY id DESC") or die("Ошибочный запрос к БД".mysql_error());
   if($result) { // Если mysql_query вернула не пустой результат
   if(!mysql_num_rows($result))
   echo "Нету людей. Скорее это ошибка. Ведь вы зарегистрированны, а вас здесь нету.";
    while ($group = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $group["name"];
        }
         }
        ?>
```

Дамп таблицы group:

```
CREATE TABLE `group` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `site` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `avatar` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `people` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `admin` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `about` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Comment: Как? Переименовать таблицу с group на другую?

Comment: Все, сменил с group на grups. Напишите ответом, я поставлю галочку.

Comment: Имя можно было не менять. Достаточно в запросе написать `group`.

Comment: Да ладно уж. Во множественном числе лучше получиться, тем более в этой таблице будут находиться все группы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо, `MySQL` считает `group` ключевым словом. Попробуйте заэкранировать `group`